# Load Testing end to end data flow from JMS to HBase

Tags: jms, hbase, performance-testing, loadrunner

The Architecture goes like:

> JMS -> KAfka -> spark -> hbase

Their is a data flow(XML) from JMS to Hbase.

My Requirement:

1. Benchmarking for various sized data which i am able to achieve using timestamp.(done)
2. Load testing the same scenario? How can achieve the whole transaction response time with the help of loadrunner.(Response time when the data reaches Hbase)?
   Below is the code to generate load on JMS queue:

   ```
   Action() {
   jms_publish_message_topic("SendMessage", 
       "hello {NewParam_2}", 
       "sampletopic");

   jms_publish_message_topic("sendXml", 
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<ns0:NotificaCollezioneTessile "
       "xmlns:ns0=\"http://carrefour.it/mdg/schemas/xsd\">\r\n    <ns0:Infolog>\r\n     "
       "   <ns0:TimeStamp>{NewParam_7}</ns0:TimeStamp>\r\n    "
       "</ns0:Infolog>\r\n    <ns0:Context>\r\n        <ns0:ContextId>"
       "ASTRA-ACCTB-VL-FIRST</ns0:ContextId>\r\n    </ns0:Context>\r\n    "
       "<ns0:CollezioneTessile>\r\n        <ns0:Anagrafica>\r\n            <ns0:Anno>"
       "2017</ns0:Anno>\r\n            <ns0:CollezioneTessileDx>"
       "CONTINUATIVO</ns0:CollezioneTessileDx>\r\n            "
       "<ns0:CollezioneTessileTipoCod>CO</ns0:CollezioneTessileTipoCod>\r\n            "
       "<ns0:DtImpianto>2017-07-10</ns0:DtImpianto>\r\n            <ns0:FDeMarca>"
       "false</ns0:FDeMarca>\r\n            <ns0:DtDec>2017-07-07+02:00</ns0:DtDec>\r\n "
       "           <ns0:DtCes>2017-10-01</ns0:DtCes>\r\n        </ns0:Anagrafica>\r\n   "
       "     <ns0:AlberoPrincipale>\r\n            <ns0:RepCod>60</ns0:RepCod>\r\n      "
       "  </ns0:AlberoPrincipale>\r\n    </ns0:CollezioneTessile>"
       "\r\n</ns0:NotificaCollezioneTessile>", 
       "fornitore");


   return 0;
   ```

   }

i will parameterize the xml data and also send the current timestamp for every run.

Please suggest any ideas to achieve end to end response time?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i have tried doing an automation where the end table records(output) will be extracted and then we will find difference between two timestamps. and then write it in another excel file. But i want to do it with Loadrunner which will help give trending graphs.

Comment: I meant, what did you try to do in LoadRunner. Your question is too broad and it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I am trying to simulate load on JMS queue and want the response time when it reaches HBase. It actually gives response time when it gets acknowledgement from Kafka.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you need help using the product for your specific usecase. You should try asking this question on our customer forum https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF#.WdB3vmiCxGM